# Curl Command in Shell Script in Azure Pipeline not working

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I'm trying to run a script which provides the status code of some url, using azure pipeline.

My Azure Yaml file:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-16.04

steps:
- script: echo Hello
  displayName: ' Welcome'
- script: cat webpages.txt
  displayName: 'display file'
- script: curl -s -w '%{http_code}\n' -o /dev/null https://www.google.co.in
  displayName: 'Checking Curl Code'
- script: cat -v script.sh
  displayName: 'Cariage retrun'
- task: ShellScript@2
  inputs:
    scriptPath: script.sh
```

My Script.sh file

```
#!/bin/sh
while read line ; do echo "$line - `curl -s -w '%{http_code}\n' -o /dev/null $line`" ;done < webpages.txt
```

webpages.txt file

```
https://www.vodafone.co.uk/good-stuff
https://www.vodafone.co.uk/help-and-information/cancel-your-account
https://www.vodafone.co.uk/help-and-information/complaints
https://www.vodafone.co.uk/help-and-information/complaints/code-of-practice
https://www.vodafone.co.uk/help-and-information/costs-and-charges
https://www.vodafone.co.uk/help-and-information/costs-and-charges/call-and-text-charges
https://www.vodafone.co.uk/help-and-information/costs-and-charges/data-charges
```

**Problem**

When I run my pipeline, the curl command is not working
and output comes as

```
2020-11-17T09:59:05.4094324Z ##[section]Starting: ShellScript
2020-11-17T09:59:05.4102534Z ==============================================================================
2020-11-17T09:59:05.4102904Z Task         : Shell script
2020-11-17T09:59:05.4103204Z Description  : Run a shell script using Bash
2020-11-17T09:59:05.4103453Z Version      : 2.165.2
2020-11-17T09:59:05.4103701Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-11-17T09:59:05.4104086Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/shell-script
2020-11-17T09:59:05.4104506Z ==============================================================================
2020-11-17T09:59:05.7637654Z [command]/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/1/s/script.sh
2020-11-17T09:59:05.7692023Z https://www.vodafone.co.uk/good-stuff
2020-11-17T09:59:05.7700780Z  - 000
2020-11-17T09:59:05.7797276Z https://www.vodafone.co.uk/help-and-information/cancel-your-account
2020-11-17T09:59:05.7798378Z  - 000
2020-11-17T09:59:05.7851183Z https://www.vodafone.co.uk/help-and-information/complaints
2020-11-17T09:59:05.7866944Z  - 000
2020-11-17T09:59:05.7908420Z https://www.vodafone.co.uk/help-and-information/complaints/code-of-practice
2020-11-17T09:59:05.7909144Z  - 000
2020-11-17T09:59:05.7967261Z https://www.vodafone.co.uk/help-and-information/costs-and-charges
2020-11-17T09:59:05.7967920Z  - 000
2020-11-17T09:59:05.8023329Z https://www.vodafone.co.uk/help-and-information/costs-and-charges/call-and-text-charges
2020-11-17T09:59:05.8024443Z  - 000
2020-11-17T09:59:05.8095527Z https://www.vodafone.co.uk/help-and-information/costs-and-charges/data-charges
```

but if I replace my curl with

```
curl -s -w '%{http_code}\n' -o /dev/null https://www.vodafone.co.uk/good-stuff
```

it gives the output at 200.

Comment: So the problem lies in `script: curl -s -w '%{http_code}\n' -o /dev/null https://www.google.co.in` or in the shell script `scriptPath: script.sh`? Both contain curl commands

Comment: Problem lies in the curl, same curl command w/o variable, "curl -s -w '%{http_code}\n' -o /dev/null https://www.google.co.in" would work fine, but if the same has a variable, curl -s -w '%{http_code}\n' -o /dev/null $line` ...it would not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I did,

1. I replaced the whole curl command with a simple curl $line
2. It gave me an error : curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL
3. So, I figured my URL is adding some unrequired values.
4. I replaced my do with

```
line=${line%$'\r'}
while read line ; do line=${line%$'\r'} ; echo "$line - `curl -s -w '%{http_code}\n' -o /dev/null $line`"; done < webpages.txt
```

and Voila it works!

Answer (score 0):

When I'm running this locally it works perfectly:

```
$ while read line ; do echo "$line - `curl -s -w '%{http_code}\n' -o /dev/null $line`" ;done < webpages.txt
https://www.vodafone.co.uk/good-stuff - 200
https://www.vodafone.co.uk/help-and-information/cancel-your-account - 200
(...)
```

I notice that a `\n` character is printed in your `echo $line`, that's probably causing the issue. What could solve it, is:

- replacing `$line` by `${line}`,
- replacing `echo` by `echo -n` to omit newlines.

Comment: Hi I tried this, locally it works perffectly, but when I run this in Azure Yaml pipeline, it's returning 200. Same script when i run in Gitlab, it works perfectly.